# Question on getting number of day from single date column

Tags: sql

[image]

Above is the screenshot of the tables for my practice. I want to extract the number of days between the earliest and latest sales made by staff 'Ali'.  I do not have any SQL IDE to run the code and want to check any problem with my code.

```
SELECT DAYDIFF(day, MAX(st.Date),  MIN(st.Date)) AS Duration
FROM SALES_TRANSACTION AS ST
LEFT JOIN SALES_MASTER AS sm
  ON sm.Product_ID = st.Product_ID
GROUP BY sm.Staff_Name
HAVING sm.Staff_Name = 'Ali'
ORDER BY st.Date DESC
```

Here is the dataset
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13XCxQgbEONU22ZDYhQq-I1u-dh3A2fPc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DAYDIFF is a product specific function.)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images. (Hard to read tiny image text, and even harder to copy and paste.)

Comment: Some kind of magic: sales made by staff 'Ali' and sm.Staff_Name = 'John'

Comment: @jarlh, I have addded the dataset. The answer is 145

Comment: @Sergey   Sorry for the typo. I have amended. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want logic more like this:

```
SELECT DAYDIFF(day, MIN(st.Date), MAX(st.Date)) AS Duration
FROM SALES_TRANSACTION ST JOIN 
     STAFF_MASTER sm
     ON sm.Staff_id = st.Staff_Id
WHERE sm.Staff_Name = 'Ali';
```

Note the changes:

- The filtering is the in `WHERE` clause rather than the `HAVING`.  In general, it is better to filter before aggregating if possible.
- The `LEFT JOIN` is replaced by a `JOIN`.  First, you need a match to get the name.  Second, the foreign key reference should be valid so an outer join should not be necessary.
- The correct table for the staff name is `STAFF_MASTER`.
- If you are using SQL Server (which has the 3 argument `DATEDIFF()` syntax), then the smaller date is the second argument.

And finally, there are many tools on the web where you can test SQL, such as [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), and [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).  You can also download free databases onto almost any platform.